# Steps to show: $\mu^x (1-\mu)^{1-x} = (1 -\mu) \exp \left[ \ln \left(\frac{\mu}{1-u} \right)x \right]$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

In *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* by Christopher M. Bishop

Equation (2.196) refers to the Bernoulli distribution:

$$\mu^x (1-\mu)^{1-x}$$

And Bishop says that expressing this as the exponential of the logarithm becomes (2.197):
$$\begin{align}
\mu^x (1-\mu)^{1-x} &= \exp \left[ x\ln{\mu} + (1-x)\ln{(1-\mu)} \right] \\
&= (1 -\mu) \exp{ \left[ \ln \left(\frac{\mu}{1-u} \right)x \right] }
\end{align}$$

I understand what he’s doing in the first shown step of (2.197). However, how does he get to the last step shown?

Comment: I went ahead and suggested an edit that made $ln$ appear as $\ln$, that bought down the first expression into the two line of steps, and that changed the braces to brackets. The first two were objective, but the latter was a gauge of general preference. If you find that this detracts from the quality of your post or is not equivalent to what you intended, please feel free to rollback the edit $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

An even easier approach is to skip the middle step.
$$\mu^x (1-\mu)^{1-x} = (1-\mu) \cdot \left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)^x.$$
Then apply the fact $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$ for any $a > 0$ to $a=\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}$.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

$$\begin{align} \mu^x (1-\mu)^{1-x} &= e^{x\ln{(\mu)} + (1-x)\ln{(1-\mu)}} \\
&= e^{x\ln{(\mu)} + \ln{(1-\mu)}-x\ln{(1-\mu)}} \\
&=(1-\mu) e^{x\ln{(\mu)} - x\ln{(1-\mu)}} \\
&=(1-\mu) e^{x(\ln{(\mu)} - \ln{(1-\mu)})}\\
&=(1-\mu) e^{\ln{\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)}x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: You missed a backslash on the RHS of the second line ;)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor fixed, thanks

Comment: No problem, buddy :)